# SSRS - Action Go To Url datetime parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SSRS Action -> Go To Url like this:

`="javascript:void(window.open('http://xxx/xxx/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDevelopment%2fReport&rs:Command=Render&Company="& Parameters!Company.Value &"&FromDate="& Parameters!FromDate.Value &"&ToDate="& Parameters!ToDate.Value &"'))"`

generated link:
`http://xxx/xxx/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Development/Report&rs:Command=Render&Company=49&FromDate=4/1/2013&ToDate=30/4/2013`

with 3 parameters:

> string Company - value: 49
>   datetime FromDate - value:  4/1/2013
>   datetime ToDate - value:    4/30/2013

All of the parameters work, but the problem is the report takes the first number in datetime parameters as day and second number as month. I need it the other way around.

Source T-SQL parameter values are yyyy-mm-dd set as default value of parameters:

> 2013-04-01 00:00:00.000
>   2013-04-30 00:00:00.000

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

if I get it right you just need to use format function and change the format the way you like

```
Format(Fields!MyDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")
```